# Height of "li" inline elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m trying to set the height of the "li" which has "display:inline" as css.
I know inline elements resets the height but I need it to be display:inline just to text align center the list.

this is my css:

```
li{
    font-size: 28px;
    border-right: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I need to fix the height to show the border height according to the text height, this is what is happening now:

[image]

Any ideas to workaround this? remember, I need the display inline to text align center the lists over the ul.

If there is other way to text-align:center the lists also would help I think...

Comment: `inline-block` doesn't count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inline` doesn't respect paddings or margins this way. You should use `display: inline-block` which does:

http://jsfiddle.net/hBz7G/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Just removed the line-height property that is making it having space from top and just giving margin of right  and padding of right to have space just from the right side.

```
li{
  font-size: 28px;
  border-right: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing, don't just post a chunk of code

Comment: Even if it were my downvote, I would not think it's too late. It's encouraging you to improve your answer, you could get an upvote if your improved answer is useful. If you don't care, you should just delete the answer

Comment: okay point noted and i explained why i did and what i did. Thanks for the encouragement.